# Difference between templates in JavaScript and design patterns

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, jquery

What is the difference between templates and design patterns in JavaScript?

I read about the template method design pattern and now I wonder how it relates to JavaScript templates (if at all).

Comment: Your question is incredibly unclear. Also this has nothing to do with php, please remove that tag.

Comment: "Suggest some of them" Yessir!

Comment: @Jose - that was a word for word copying from a test or homework assignment, thus the imperative wording

Answer (score 3):

Templates (in the Javascript world) are a method to display Javascript (model) data in an HTML (or other) view.

[Design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29) are known (and battle tested) methods of solving common problems.

Really, Javascript templates could be construed as a design pattern (depending on who you ask ;)).

Answer (score 2):

Design patterns are used to solve commonly encountered problems related to software design.
Once you know how to solve a particular problem, when that problem presents again you can reuse the same approach you used before, the same pattern.

Patterns are not related to JavaScript only, but to every language.

The JavaScript Templates you are referring about may be a technique used to generate data in the document, originally called [Micro-templating](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) by the inventor, John Resig (jQuery).

[Here](http://www.gethifi.com/blog/javascript-templates-and-how-we-use-them-in-hifi)'s an article to better understand them.

And [here](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#whatisapattern)'s one for applying common design patterns in JS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. please suggest some javascript templates

Comment: [Embeddedjs](http://embeddedjs.com/) is a library to help you with templates. And [TrimPath](http://www.wdvl.com/Authoring/JavaScript/TrimPath/Alessandro_Lacava02092010.html) is an example of JS template.